# How to set more AWS dynamoDb table properties using AWS CDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cdk

I am very new to AWS and I have been reading the dynamoDb SDK documentation and the properties that you can specify when creating a Table are far more than the properties that you pass when creating a table using AWS CDK.

SDK example:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000"
});

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "Movies",
    KeySchema: [       
        { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        { AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE" }  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [       
        { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

CDK example:

```
import * as dynamodb from '@aws-cdk/aws-dynamodb';


const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'Hits', {
    partitionKey: { name: 'path', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING }
});
```

here are all the props you can set which are more high level table related settings:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.Table.html

so for example if I want to set the provision throughput in CDK how do I do it? or set AttributeDefinitions, or indexes?

Do I wait unit table creation is done and then modify the table properties via the SDK UpdateTable call?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#updateTable-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamodb is pretty much entirely implemented in CDK, but some of the properties are a bit more difficult to find if you aren't very familiar with.

Billing Mode is the property for  Provisioned or on demand read/write capacity. It is a constant, so it would be used something like

```
billingMode: aws_dynamodb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

With CDK you often have to dive a little bit into the documentation to find what you want, but for the mainstream services - Lambda, S3, Dynamo - these are fully implemented in CDK.

And in any case, for other services that may not be, you can use any of the functions that start with `Cfn` as these are escape hatches that allow you to basically implement direct cloud formation template jsons from cdk

Answer (score 1):

> Billing Mode
>
> DynamoDB supports two billing modes:
>
> PROVISIONED - the default mode where the table and global secondary
> indexes have configured read and write capacity.
>
> PAY_PER_REQUEST - on-demand pricing and scaling. You only pay for what
> you use and there is no read and write capacity for the table or its
> global secondary indexes.

see the Billing Mode attribute:
[cdk docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-dynamodb-readme.html#:%7E:text=sortKey%20(optional)%20properties.-,Billing%20Mode,-DynamoDB%20supports%20two)